# How do I view how Prolog got to its result/the path it took?

Tags: prolog, logic-programming

I have a simple Prolog predicate that spits accepts a variable, `Result`, that calculates a result then stores it in `Result` to be viewed. Sometimes I'm unsure how it comes to the answer it stores in `Result` and I'm curious if there's a way in Prolog to get it to show how it got to the answer, I guess show the path it took and how it built it up?

The predicate is something simple like `solve(Input, Result).` and `Result` can sometimes be peculiar.

Comment: You can use graphical debugger in SWI-Prolog: http://www.swi-prolog.org/gtrace.html

Comment: [Almost every prolog implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Prolog_implementations) includes a way to debug code, it seems. It's just a matter of looking up the documentation for whatever you're using.